# Помогите вставить значение полученного post

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который получает данные со стороннего сайта:

```
<?php 

$url = $_POST["url"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$title = $_POST["title"]; 
// инициализация сеанса 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
............

$page_source = preg_replace('/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/si', 
'<title>сюда вставить полученный POST</title>', 
$page_source);
```

Как в `<title>` вставить полученные из POST данные? echo там не подойдет.
Можно ли вставить POST только в том случае если он передан и оставить все без изменений `preg_replace` если POST не получен (пуст)?

Спасибо!

Comment: и при чем тут cURL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
$url = $_POST["url"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

function renderTitle($math) {
   $title = empty($_POST["title"]) ? $math[1] : $_POST["title"];
   return "<title>{$title}</title>";
}

$page_source = preg_replace_callback('/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/si', 'renderTitle', $page_source);
```

c `$math[1]` не уверен почитайте в мануалах на php.net

Comment: Shnur, большое спасибо! Работает именно так как нужно, $math[1] подошел. Спасибо!